# How to simulate informative censoring in a Cox PH model?

Tags: simulation, cox-model, censoring, weibull-distribution

I wish to simulate events from a Cox PH model where the censoring is informative, and to compare parameter estimator quality with estimates obtained from data generated by a Cox PH model with non-informative censoring. However I am struggling to do this, and I conclude rather than a technical flaw in my code I instead do not understand what is meant by informative and un-informative censoring.

My approach is to simulate an event time $T$ dependent on a vector of covariates $x$ having hazard function $h(t|x)=\lambda\exp(\beta'x)vt^{v-1}$. This corresponds to $T\sim Weibull(\lambda(x),v)$, where the scale parameter $\lambda(x)=\lambda\exp(\beta'x)$ depends on $x$ and the shape parameter $v$ is fixed. I have $N$ subjects where $T_{i}\sim Weibull(\lambda_{T}(x_{i}),v_{T})$, $\lambda_{T}(x_{i})=\lambda_{T}\exp(\beta_{T}'x_{i})$, for $i=1,...,N$. Here I assume the regression coefficients are $p$-dimensional.

I generate informative censoring times $C_{i}\sim Weibull(\lambda_{C}(x_{i}),v_{C})$, $\lambda_{C}(x_{i})=\lambda_{C}\exp(\beta_{C}'x_{i})$ and compute $Y^{I}_{i}=min(T_{i},C_{i})$ and a censored flag $\delta^{I}_{i}=1$ if $Y^{I}_{i}\leq C_{i}$ (an observed event), and $\delta^{I}_{i}=0$ if $Y^{I}_{i}> C_{i}$ (informatively censored: event not observed). I am convinced this is informative censoring because as long as $\beta_{T}\not=0$ and $\beta_{C}\not=0$ then for each subject the data generating process for $T$ and $C$ both depend on $x$.

In contrast I generate non-informative censoring times $D_{i}\sim Weibull(\lambda_{D}\exp(\beta_{D}),v_{D})$, and compute $Y^{NI}_{i}=min(T_{i},D_{i})$ and a censored flag $\delta^{NI}_{i}=1$ if $Y^{NI}_{i}\leq D_{i}$ (an observed event), and $\delta^{NI}_{i}=0$ if $Y^{NI}_{i}> D_{i}$ (non-informatively censored: event not observed). Here $\beta_{D}$ is a scalar.

I "scale" the simulation by choosing the $\lambda_{T}$, $\lambda_{C}$ and $\lambda_{D}$ parameters such that on average $T_{i}<C_{i}$ and $T_{i}<D_{i}$ to achieve $X\%$ of censored subjects for both $Y^{I}_{i}$ and $Y^{NI}_{i}$.

The problem is that even for say $30\%$ censoring (which I think is high), the Cox PH parameter estimates using both $Y^{I}_{i}$ and $Y^{NI}_{i}$ are unbiased when I expected the estimates using $Y^{I}_{i}$ to be biased, and I think I see why: however different $\beta_{C}$ is from $\beta_{T}$, a censored subject can presumably influence the estimation of $\beta_{T}$ only by affecting the set of subjects at risk at any time $t$, but this does not change the fact that every single $Y_{i}^{I}$ with $\delta_{i}^{I}=1$ will have been generated using $\beta_{T}$ only. Thus I do not see how my simulation can possibly produce biased estimates for $\beta_{T}$ using $Y_{i}^{I}$.

But then what is informative censoring if not based on this approach?

Edit: The code below I think demonstrates the point I refer to in my comments below this question, that is the bias in the estimation of the hazard function is not related to the bias in the estimation of the regression parameters. In my opinion (which may be wrong) the censoring in this code is not informative since the censoring does not depend on the covariates. If anybody can show me how to amend the code to produce informative censoring that produces biased regression estimates that would be great - then perhaps I will understand what informative censoring is.

```
##install.packages("muhaz")
library(muhaz)

censRand <- function(time, cens.t.5){  # cens.t.5 is the t 1/2 of censor process
  ctime <- rexp(n = length(time), rate = 1/cens.t.5)
  event <- (time <= ctime)
  t_obs <- pmin(time, ctime)
  return(data.frame(Times=t_obs, event=event))
}

N=10000

#simulate a hazard of the form;
# h(t|x) = lambda*exp[(beta_age*age)+(beta_treat*treat)]
# Do this by drawing from an exponential distribution
beta_age = 0.5
beta_treat = -1
age = rnorm(N,33,2)
treat = rbinom(N,1,0.5)
lp = (beta_age*age)+(beta_treat*treat)
lambda=0.000001
time=rexp(N, lambda*exp(lp))

##censoring times
ctime <- censRand( time, 0.1)
pc_cen = round((length(ctime[ctime[,2]==FALSE,2])/N)*100,2)


##plots
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
tit = paste("CTTE (censored = ",toString(pc_cen)," %)")
hist(time,breaks=20,main="TTE")
hist(ctime[,1],breaks=20,main=tit)



##fit the Cox model
cox_obj = coxph(Surv(ctime[ ,1],ctime[ ,2],type=c("right"))~age+treat )
summary(cox_obj)

plot( muhaz( ctime[ ,1], ctime[,2]) )
```

Comment: If you want an example of a censoring strategy that does bias the estimate for the X effect look at  the method used by the questioner in : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162104/hazard-estimate-of-muhaz-function

Comment: Thanks @DWin. I looked at the link you gave, and as far as I could understand, the code therein showed how the baseline hazard function estimate becomes worse as time increases (due I think to the ever decreasing numbers of subjects at risk). I amended this code keeping the same censoring function. I also simulated covariate effects. If I choose the sample size high enough I can get unbiased estimates from coxph even though the same degradation of the hazard function occurs for increasing time. Thus the bias you speak of I think does not relate to estimation of the regression parameters.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post the code here in a comment! I think I need to assume a model for the event times beyond the point of censoring - this would be a counterfactual event. I think if this counterfactual model is the same as the event times model then censoring will only affect the baseline survival function estimate (shifts it down?), but the regression parameters remain well estimated. Only if the counterfactual model is different does censoring make a difference - i.e. running a coxph on the "full" data if we could see it would produce a different result than on the observed data.

Comment: Partial response: Code from a questioner should be added to the question with an edit. Too busy at the moment to respond to the more substantive portion of your question , but if code clarifies it, then please use `edit`.